# PHP Workerman - client websocket connection issue

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'am jsut trying to set up very simple connection between Workerman lib for PHP and javascript client. I can't get how to set the url for websocket properly on the javascript client.

[Workerman lib](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman)

Actually I'am using Cloud9 for testing purpose, then I want to move this sample to shared hosting.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

This is my php sample `start.php`:

```
<?php
require_once '/home/ubuntu/workspace/workerman/vendor/autoload.php';
use Workerman\Worker;

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:2346");

// 4 processes
$ws_worker->count = 4;

// Emitted when new connection come
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection)
{
    echo "New connection\n";
};

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    // Send hello $data
    $connection->send('hello ' . $data);
};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function($connection)
{
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

This is my client sample `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Workerman Sockets Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Hello</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // How to set url for websocket in this case???
        var socket = new WebSocket("wss://project-user.c9users.io:2346/workerman/test/");

        socket.onopen = function() {
          alert("Connection established.");
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
          if (event.wasClean) {
            alert('The connection is closed.');
          } else {
            alert('Connection failure'); // for example, the server process is "killed"
          }
          alert('Code: ' + event.code + ' reason: ' + event.reason);
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
          alert("Received data " + event.data);
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
          alert("Error" + error.message);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I run my script with this command `$ php start.php`:

```
Workerman[start.php] start in DEBUG mode
----------------------- WORKERMAN -----------------------------
Workerman version:3.5.4          PHP version:5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22
------------------------ WORKERS -------------------------------
user          worker        listen                    processes status
ubuntu        none          websocket://0.0.0.0:2346   4         [OK] 
----------------------------------------------------------------
Press Ctrl+C to quit. Start success.
```

Then I'am running apache server and there is timeout error when I open my page: `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

So, could somebody gave an advice how to set websocket address on the client in this case to use it with Workerman lib properly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first assumption is that this port is not opened by Cloud9.

Reading their documentation kind of confirms that:
https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application

> Available ports on a hosted Cloud9 workspace If you're developing a
>   server application, please note that you need to listen to 0.0.0.0
>   ($IP) and 8080 ($PORT). Listening to this port will enable your app to
>   be viewable at http://-.c9users.io
>
> You can also bind to ports 8081, and 8082, which can be accessed by
>   http://-.c9users.io:8081 and
>   http://-.c9users.io:8082 respectively.
>
> Please note that 8080, 8081, and 8082 are the only available ports on
>   a hosted Cloud9 workspace.

Comment: I've just tried to change websocket address on my client to `wss://project-user.c9users.io:8080` and on the server to `websocket://0.0.0.0:8080` and then new error occured: `failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

Comment: Does this host has SSL/TLS enabled?

Comment: Oh, it was only necessary to change port to 8081 and restrt server, thanks!